# What does the bracket in this expression mean

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am modifying another developer's code and I don't know what the [0] bracket following the string means in this context, can someone explain to me?  My first thought is it is referring to the first column of GridView1 but that isn't the correct way to designate a column is it? BTW the string values in the if statement are 7 digit numbers expressed as strings. The first column is the DataKey column.

```
if (GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString()[0] != '5' && GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 2) != "95")
            {
                LinkButton1.Visible = false;
                LinkButton2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                LinkButton1.Visible = true;
                LinkButton2.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: It's indexer syntax. In the case of `String`, it grabs the character at the specified index. `.ToString()[0] != '5'` basically checks if the first character is not a 5.

Comment: this is a brittle approach because it relies on `SelectedValue` to have a length greater than zero. attempting to read a char by index from a zero-length string causes an exception.

Comment: @itsme86 Oh! Ok! that now makes sense. and dlatikay  I supposed I should do a check for greater than before the if. I will clean it up.  itsme86 offer as answer and I will ok it.

Comment: @GrantWinney, i wouldn't say "array of characters". As arrays of some type are data types in .NET that are mutable and can be worked upon by the utility methods of System.Array (and countless other methods), whereas sequences of characters forming strings are not, i would avoid the phrase you used ;-)

Comment: I feel so silly. I never thought of a string as an array of characters before but I should have since substring is looking at indexes. My bad. Geez thanks for the clarification everyone. Just never saw this syntax before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String Accessing Individual Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#accessing-individual-characters)

> You can use array notation with an index value to acquire read-only
>   access to individual characters

```
if (GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString()[0] != '5' && GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 2) != "95")
```

As noted in the comments, both the below will throw if there are not enough characters

```
GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString()[0]
GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 2)
```

Also as per [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) calling this twice is redundant and also messy

```
GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

When you can

```
var something = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Lastly, normally you would check this for sanity sake, Like

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(something) && something.Length >= 2)
   if (something[0] != '5' && something.Substring(0, 2) != "95")
```

Anyway, have fun stringing

Comment: I know I am not supposed to say it but I learned much from everyone's comments. Thank you @TheGeneral for the reference. I was so focused on what the brackets' connection to GridView1 was that I overlooked that I should look at string manipulation.